# How to Write horizontal bullet point list in latex?

Tags: list, latex, horizontallist

I want to write horizontal bullet points in latex. How can I do that? as far as I got some solution on the internet is a vertical list with numbers.

How can I get bullet points instead of numbers?

My current code is something like this-

```
  \documentclass[twoside = false, % doppelseitiger Druck
    DIV=17,                 % DIV Faktor für Satzspiegelberechnung, sie Doku zu KOMA Script
    BCOR=15mm,              % Bindekorrektur
    chapterprefix=false,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    pagesize,               % write pagesize to DVI or PDF
    fontsize=11pt,          % use this font size
    paper=a4,               % use ISO A4
    bibliography=totoc,     % write bibliography-chapter to table of contents
    index=totoc,            % write index-chapter to table of contents
    cleardoublepage=plain,  % \cleardoublepage generates pages with pagestyle empty
     headings=big,          % A4/B5
    listof=flat,            % improved list of tables
    numbers=noenddot
  ]{scrbook}
\begin{inparaenum}
    \item  A
    \item  B
    \item  C
    \item  D
    \item  E
    \item  F
    \item  G
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see you class, packages and everything else to compile your code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I have been using a lot of packages. but nothing related to the list or specifically the horizontal list. I just want to put dots instead of numbers for my horizontal list. I have no idea which package is useful for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `paralist` package... use the `inparaitem` instead of `inparaenum`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
This list includes the following :
\begin{inparaitem}
\item option A
\item option B 
\item option C
\end{inparaitem}\\
Please choose an option
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

***For horizontal list:***

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Text before list.
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item My first in list.
  \item My second in list.
\end{enumerate*}
Text after list.

\end{document}
```

For more examples, please visit [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. It still enumerate the list. I want bullet points or lets say dots for example instead of numbers for my list.